# Printing issue with non-administrator user on win10

Tags: c#, windows-10, administrator

We are migrating to win10 and faced an issue, that our c# printing app does not work with non-administrator user. 
Error message:

> The operation completed successfully

Error stack trace:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController.OnEndPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PrintControllerWithStatusDialog.OnEndPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()
   at MyApp.MyApp.<>c__DisplayClass101_0.<CallAndWait>b__0()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.PrivateProcessMessage(RuntimeMethodHandle md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
   at MyApp.MyApp.PrintingMethod.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
   at MyApp.MyApp.CallAndWait(MethodWithoutArgs action, Int32 timeout)
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I think some access should be given to my user? But for what?

Comment: Does printing from LibreOffice Writer or Word work?

Comment: we don't have office installed, but it works from notepad started from same user as our app

Comment: `does not work with non-administrator user`. Does it work as an administrator?

Comment: Yes. but I need to work as normal user. But what grants I need to give for it? This is strange that on another win10 computer this app works OK under normal user.